# Is it possible to explicitly call an exported Go WebAssembly function from JS?

Tags: javascript, go, webassembly

**Is it possible to call a Go WebAssembly function, other than `main`, in Javascript?**

Let me first show what I did. My Go functions are defined as follows:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("it works!")
}

func add(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}
```

I can only invoke the `main` function:

```js
const go = new Go();

const data   = await fetch("http://localhost:3333/main.wasm");
const result = await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(data, go.importObject);

go.run(result.instance);
```

which returns `it works!` as expected.

However, whenever I try to invoke the `add` function, I receive `TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined at Welcome.getWasm`, because both `result.exports`, `result.instance.exports` do not contain my function. I also tried capitalizing the Go function, but at no avail.

Thus, I started wondering what could be a problem – **is it even possible to call a random Go function from Javascript?** Or can I only call the default `main()` function?

Comment: The only working solution I found is to make `add()` a global JS function, by using `js.Global().Set("add", js.FuncOf(add))`, and changing `add()` signature to `func add(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{}`, and then using `add` in a global JS scope, which is, in my opinion, kind of *dirty*

Comment: It has own unresolved [issue in Golang repo](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25612)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is possible. You can "export" a function to the global context (i.e. window in browser, global in nodejs):

```
js.Global().Set("add", js.FuncOf(addFunction))
```

Where "add" is the name that you can use to call the function from Javascript (window.add) and "addFunction" is a Go function in your Go code, next to your main.

Note that "addFunction" must follow that method signature:

```
package main

import (
    "syscall/js"
)

func addFunction(this js.Value, p []js.Value) interface{} {
    sum := p[0].Int() + p[1].Int()
    return js.ValueOf(sum)
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan struct{}, 0)

    js.Global().Set("add", js.FuncOf(addFunction))

    <-c
}
```

After "go.run(result.instance);" you can run.

```
go.run(result.instance);
add(100,200);
```