# How do I use some wasm files for other javascript projects which are not dependent on wasm-pack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rust, nodes, wasm-bindgen

Can I call functions declared in wasm files from any javascript?

Wasm files were built by wasm-pack with Rust lang, wasm-pack, wasm-bindgen and webpack. They are working fine in the original environment.

I want to use some wasm files for other javascript projects which are not dependent on wasm-pack. For example , a simplest browser hello-world demo project developed in node.js.

Edit: I have read general concepts on how to call wasm functions from javascript. But I cannot apply it to my situation by myself. For example, the article only talk about on a build wasm file. But for my case, there exist many files in the pkg directory of which some files are js files. Can I neglect all such js files in pkg directory?

[General concept](https://ihsavru.medium.com/loading-webassembly-modules-in-javascript-dc09fbd5eac2)

Comment: This subject seems to be covered in detail [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Using_the_JavaScript_API).

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Please help me. I cannot apply the general techniques to my situation without any hint.

Comment: If your situation is specific, you should show us some code that illustrates your problem.  From the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them."*

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56398142/is-it-possible-to-explicitly-call-an-exported-go-webassembly-function-from-js

Comment: @RobertHarvey, It would be the same if it was the simplest greeting demo function. Because many js files are generated in pkg directory which are not mentioned in your link.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon, It help me to understand the general answer more. But the general answer does not mention on js files output in pkg directory at same time the wasm file was output. Can I neglect those js files in pkg directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me one question appears

> But for my case, there exist many files in the pkg directory of which
> some files are js files. Can I neglect all such js files in pkg
> directory?

These files are the glue between `js` and `rust-wasm`. You can neglect them, but then they needs be to replaced with some other glue.

To me simplest is example [without-a-bundler](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/tree/master/examples/without-a-bundler)

At deployment 3 files are needed:

`pkg/without_a_bundler_bg.wasm`,
`pkg/without_a_bundler.js`,
`index.html`

At runtime rust is called from js here:
[call rust-wasm add function](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/blob/master/examples/without-a-bundler/index.html#L47)

This function call is done within the `wasm-bindgen` glue, so e.g. unknown from dev console. Haven't tried, but still for this small example the generated `pkg/without_a_bundler.js` is only 195 lines so for investigation could be manageable to transplant into an other project.